# Working on a Python project for a salesman. Getting "cannot assign to operator" error

Tags: python

I'm working on a project in Python for a salesman. The project takes the pay from hours worked for the week and the percentage from commission of sales per week and adds them together to give the total weekly pay of the salesman. The problem I'm running into is dividing the sales amount with the percent they receive from each sale. The error is "cannot assign to operator"

```
#Prompt user for the number of hours worked that week 
hours_worked = int(input("How many hours did you work this week? \n"))

#Define hourly wage
per_hour = 30

#Multiply the hourly wage and hours worked that week
total_hours_pay = hours_worked * per_hour

#Prompt user for the number of sales made that week
sales_made = int(input("How many sales did you make this week? \n"))

#Amount of each sale
sales = 250

#Determine commission of each sale
25 / sales = commission

#Multiply the commission times the amount of sales made to retrieve amount of total commission pay
total_sales_pay = sales_made * commission

#Add total commission pay from sales with the total hours pay to get the weekly total
total_week_pay = total_sales_pay + total_hours_pay


print(total_week_pay)
```

[image: Picture of the error received]

Comment: What do you expect the line commented with "#Determine commission of each sale" to do?

Comment: Assignment is not symmetric. `x = y` is not the same as `y = x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote:

```
25 / sales = commission
```

But when assigning something to a variable, you need to put the variable at the start of the statement.

Try

```
commission = 25 / sales
```

Answer (score 0):

`25 / sales = commission` this line throws the error. I think it should be `comission = 25 / sales`. You try to assign the value of `comission` to the result of `25 / sales` which does not work.